# adding double quotes at the start and end of a string

Tags: matlab

I have a string:

```
str = Earth is round
```

How do i add a double quotes in the start and end of it? The result should be :

```
str = "Earth is round"
```

I'm using MATLAB 2013 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

You can use the following syntax:

```
res = ['"' 'Earth is round' '"']
```

**Result example**

script

```
['"' 'Earth is round' '"']
'Earth is round'
```

output

```
ans = "Earth is round"
ans = Earth is round
```